# Force quit Python script / edit rc.local?

Tags: raspbian

So, I was trying to set a Python script to start when the Raspberry Pi turns on (using Raspbian). That Python script includes a shutdown line.

So my Pi starts, successfully runs my script, then shuts down. ...so, I cant get "in" to the Pi.

Pressing CTRL X, Q, CTRL ALT Q or X doesn't stop the Python script. I also tried holding Shift on startup to see if I can get into safe mode, but it doesn't work...the script is still run.

How can I either update rc.local, or exit the Python script, so I can get to the desktop?

Answer (score 2):

You could have changed the python script from another Linux computer. Just mount the SD card and edit the script.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it by logging in via SSH connection and doing `sudo nano /etc/RC.local` and the quickly deleting the line that calls the .py, save and exit.

Fortunately I had a 25 second sleep timer before shutdown, otherwise I still don't know how I would have done it.

Edit: I don't yet consider this "the answer" since if I didn't set a `sleep()` for enough time to connect via SSH, I wouldn't know what to do.

Comment: And that is how Batman solves problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Raspbian via NOOBs you can access the NOOBs menue by holding the shift-key during start-up. In the menue, click on the `edit config`-button in the top of the window. Select the `cmdline.txt`-tab and add an `s` separated by a space to the end of the line. After exiting NOOBs, your Raspberry should boot into an emergency-terminal from which you'd be able to change any script.